# Post to Office365 Group Connector(Webhook) using Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365connectors

I am trying to post a simple message to a O365 'Incoming Webhook' using powershell. Here is the code:

```
$url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/webhook/.......'

$body = @"
{
    "text": "Hello World!"
    "title": "Today"
}
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

But get this error:

```
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : System.Net.HttpWebRequest
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
ErrorDetails          : Invalid webhook request
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 10
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

if i leave out the `-Contentype` parameter i get this error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.
Trace ID: c4b77459-3915-475e-8125-fa2db9fd11e8
Correlation ID: 0ba64202-db52-4a96-8f44-a87b7f009170
Timestamp: 2016-03-27 07:48:02Z
```

anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message body is not a valid json snippet due to a missing comma after "text" field.

Changed to

```
$body = @"
{
    "text": "Hello World!",
    "title": "Today"
}
"@
```

and it works for me.

Comment: thanks for the reply...yup that was a silly omission but even after the correction i still get the error - `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.`........ seems it wants me to specify a `Tenant Identifier` which should already be in the URl so not sure why it is ignoring it.

Comment: Could you post the url here?

Comment: sure...i can always delete this :)....'https://outlook.office365.com/webhook/937f8641-7c60-4323-8f97-77e9025a9304@bf44171c-49ef-4d4a-8b57b8eee9cbadb5/IncomingWebhook/7c40ff0aaf1545b49b57674f121f8c52/d85a6489-1f65-4ca3-8e29-6dc37fde9985'

Comment: I created a new webhook and you know what this one works with the same exact code..go figure...anyway thanks for confirming that this works. I am marking your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the direction.  I was trying to test out an Azure WebHook. It would work on the Test method of the web page; even copied the JSON body from the page to powershell and it wouldn't work.  The key was apparently specifying the

```
-ContentType "application/json"
```

However, something I found interesting, is that WebHooks in Teams ***do*** work with the default content type (which is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") as the example post Stefan Stranger posted:

[Use WebHooks Connect to Send Data from PowerShell to Microsoft Teams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/11/03/use-webhook-connector-to-send-data-from-powershell-to-microsoft-teams/)

Nice shortcut for them, but looks best to always specify the content type for WebHooks to be safe.